# Percentage of patients worldwide who have electronic medical records managed by a software company founded in a given country

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset containing:

- Percentage of patients worldwide who have electronic medical records managed by a software company founded in a given country.

Or even better (since more fine-grained):

- Percentage of patients worldwide who have electronic medical records managed by a given software company.

Example: [Epic Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Systems) software hold medical records of 54% of patients in the U.S. and 2.5% of patients worldwide.

Ideally:

- evolution of these percentages throughout the year